# Is it possible to give dynamic component to <Route> in react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, react-router-dom

We already know how to pick and render component dynamically :

```
import CompA  from './CompA';
import CompB  from './CompB';

var componentSet = {
 'compa': CompA,
 'compb': CompB
}

var type = 'compa' 
var TargetComp = componentSet[type];
...
return <TargetComp />
```

But I have had no success when trying to integrate it with `<Route>` component:

```
class DynamicRoute extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Route path="/compa" render={()=> <TargetComp /> }/>
        );
    }
}
// Error message:
// Content.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned.- 
// You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

Appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this for v4?  I typically use the component prop instead of render. Would this work?

`<Route path="/compA" component={TargetComp}/>`

Comment: Yes, I'm using v4, unfortunately I have tried this but it not work.

Comment: I think you have a simple typo actually 
This line ```var TargetComp = componentSet[compa];``` would give an error unless there's more code you are hiding, as compa is not defined as a variable anywhere... so componentSet[compa] is likely evaluating componentSet[undefined] which would return null.  Change it to `componentSet[type]`

Comment: Thanks, I just correct that! but it just typo on the example shows here.

Comment: @Carr Hey did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access route properties in the component (such as `match`, `location` or `history` like in `this.props.history` in the component's code) rendered via `Route` you can pass props into the component in this way:

```
<Route path="/compA" component={(props) => (<compA {...props} myProp={this.state.myProp} />) } />
```